# npm install --global foundation-cli doesn't work

Tags: python, npm, zurb-foundation, frontend

I have windows 10, node 8.11.1. I want to install foundation-cli globaly (as local it doesn't work too). But the instalation doesn't work. I have these errors on any console (powerShell, gitBash, jetBrains):

```
PS C:\> npm install --global foundation-cli
npm WARN deprecated bower@1.8.4: We don't recommend using Bower for new projects. Please consider Yarn and Webpack or Parcel. You can read how to migrate legacy project here: https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.11: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm ERR! path C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\foundation-cli\node_modules\npm\node_modules\ansistyles
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\foundation-cli\node_modules\npm\node_modules\ansistyles' -> 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\foundation-cli\node_modules\npm\node_modules\.ansistyles.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-10-05T12_43_07_631Z-debug.log
```

I suspect that here the problem is with the python path.  I've got microsoft build tools, I tried :

`npm config set python "C:\python27\python.exe"`

But it doesn't help. Nothing happens.
Have you got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

this has probably nothing to do with Python.

What does `npm --version` output?
If it is not `6.4.1` try `npm i -g npm@latest` to upgrade npm.

Also try to disable any active antivirus scanner during the installation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't help. I also tried [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/master/README.md) manual for windows and [this](https://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/55790-npm-install-cant-find-pythonexe), and it doesn't help too. My powers ran out, and I gave up. Now I am using ubuntu what seems to me to be the only possible solution.